# Store date in MongoDB without considering the timezone

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime, timezone

Which is the best way to store a date in MongoDB without considering the timezone?

I try to explain the problem with an example:

Giuseppe in Italy created an invoce in date `"December 15, 2014"`, when the system store this date, in MongoDB will be stored `"2014-12-14T23:00:00.000Z"`.

John in UK read the invoice and see `"December 14, 2014"` as the invoice date.

Obviously this information is wrong becouse also Jhon should see `"December 15, 2014"` as the invoice date, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whole dates should *not* be placed in a `Date` object.  Despite the name, `Date` represents a date *and a time*.  If the value you're working with represents a *whole* date, rather than a specific time on that date, then you should store the value in another format.

Options are:

- A string in `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD` format
- An integer number of whole days since some reference point.

Comment: Respectfully this is completely incorrect. The representation of how **JavaScript** handles the instantation of dates is exactly how I have shown it. The terms are not equal and either represent a local time or a UTC time as is demonstrated. The arguments to instantation are more that what you give as an example as valid options therefore this is wrong.

Comment: You are correct about how JavaScript behaves when you pass the string into the `Date` object constructor.  I am advocating for *not* using a `Date` object for this scenario.

Comment: String Length: characters * 8 = "YYYYMMDD" = 64bits. Length of MongoDB Date object = 64bits... Wasted effort for "YYYYMMDD" and wasted effort & space if use "YYYY-MM-DD"... The whole days since some reference point will work though and could be worth it if you're pushed for memory.

Comment: MattJohnson's answer works for this scenario: A user registers to an app in New York. Then he moves to the California. If we use MongoDB date object to store his date of birth value, we should handle use users position (country or utc info) data to show and evaluate right date value in the app. Otherwise if user's dob value is "1972-01-01T00:00:00", when the app running in California, dob seems as "1971-12-31T21:00:00". So there are two choices to store date , 1. store as a string 2. store as an ISODate object, also store registering the position of the user to show right dob date.

Comment: @Forbesmyester does your company charge you for every bit spent? XD

Comment: @Beelphegor No but your database will, in speed.

Answer (score -1):

This means "you did it wrong". Good database practice has long been to store dates in UTC or Zulu time format. So what you should have done ( at least in JavaScript notation ) is this:

```
var  myDate = new Date ("2014-12-15");
```

And you should have considered that the date string you fed in was already converted from your local time to a UTC time, or just feed your object anyway since that is what the driver will do.

JavaScript has funny ways of interpreting the date "string" provided. So for example:

```
var  myDate = new Date ("2014/12/15");
```

Actually provides a date object in your "local" timezone to your application. Probably not what you really want in most circumstances.

**Best Practice**. Cannot emphasize that enough. The "universal time constant" is the **only** way you ever store date data. Otherwise you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Respectfully - I can't disagree with you more.  UTC is meaningless for whole dates without a time component.  This is a common source of errors, when a business date is is assumed to mean "midnight" - which when shifted to UTC or some other time zone might change the date.  Whole dates should be stored as whole dates, and nothing more.   Also - even with a time component, storing as UTC is not always the best practice.  That is sound for recording past/present data, but does not hold up when scheduling *future* data, as time zone rules can change!

Comment: Also, (nitpick) - UTC stands for "Coordinated Universal Time", not "Universal Time Constant".  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Etymology) to understand why the characters are out of sequence.