# How to save mongoose date-time in particular time-zone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, timezone

Mongoose is saving date-time as `ISODate("2017-04-25T09:40:48.193Z")`in UTC format. How can i change its time zone to my local server timezone. So i need not to change the time every time i retrieve it from db. Here is my model schema:

```
var MyModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        id: Number,
        description: String,
        created: {type: Date},
        modified: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    },
    {
        collection: 'my'
    }
);
```

PS: I am aware that it is preferred to save time in UTC format but here my requirement is to save it in specified time-zone.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise against this even if it's feasible. You really don't want to store timestamps in a server-local time zone. Why is your server time zone so special? It's more likely to be useful to convert the information to the *viewer's* time zone when they want to check logs or whatever? Were you going to store *just* a local date/time? If so, that would lose information over DST "fall back" transitions... and would cause horrible problems if you ever change your server time zone or have multiple time zones. UTC is the *right* time zone for timestamps.)

Comment: As for your PS - if someone else is pushing you to do something which is a bad idea, it's your responsibility to push back against that. Don't just go along with bad ideas.

Comment: The *server's* time zone is absolutely irrelevant.  However, you might have a valid need to store a date-only value, such as storing a birthday. For that, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27492162/634824).  The same might apply for a local date and time that is timezoneless, but it does not apply for the created and modified dates you showed here.  Those should *always* use UTC, via Mongo's `ISODate` object.

Answer (score 0):

Even thought it is not a good practice to store time in local format but this might help -

```
date = new Date(); //2017-04-25T06:23:36.510Z
date.toLocaleTimeString();  //'11:53:36 AM'
localDate = ""+d;  //'Tue Apr 25 2017 11:53:36 GMT+0530 (IST)'
```

changes will be done where you are saving the Object -

```
var date = new Date(); //2017-04-25T06:23:36.510Z
date.toLocaleTimeString();  //'11:53:36 AM'
var localDate = ""+d;  //'Tue Apr 25 2017 11:53:36 GMT+0530 (IST)'

var newModel = new ModelSchema()
newModel.description = 'Something';
newModel.created = locaDate;
newModel.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
    throw err;
    return done(null, newUser);
});
```

Comment: with my current mongoose schema, how will I save this in db?

Comment: I have made changes according to your request please have a look

Answer (score 0):

you can save users timezone and while updating add the time zone value to this new object. Better to use moment.js to convert this.
[moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. Try this one for Asia/Calcutta this can be stored as Date type in Mongoose

```
function getCurrentIndianDateTime(){
    var moment = require('moment-timezone');
    var time = moment.tz('Asia/Calcutta').format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss");
    return new Date(time);
}
```