# How to create correct new Date() from "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I'm getting data (including date fields) from a Google Sheets document and importing into MongoDB (via Mongo Realm, although I suspect Node, Lambda etc would be the same).

The date field in sheets is data validated as a date (and date is chosen via date picker) but when I console.log the `typeof` the variable I get in shows as a `string` with the value like `"Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020"`.

If I run it through `new Date()` logging reports it is `NaN-aN-aN` and when it hits Mongo it shows as `0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00`.

Does anyone know how to to get the date in the Google Sheet as a Date in Mongo?  The JSON schema on the collection for that field is

```
 "purchase_date": {
      "bsonType": "date"
    },
```

I'm also trying to insert a year `2020` into Mongo as a Date type if anyone knows how to specify that?

Comment: Can you use moment.js for this ?

Comment: `console.log(new Date('Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020').toString());`. Looks valid to me.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*Store date in MongoDB without considering the timezone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483334/store-date-in-mongodb-without-considering-the-timezone). Are you getting dates from Google Sheets as Date objects or strings?

Comment: sorry @StackSlave that shows 'Invalid Date' for me

Answer (score 0):

You can format as you want with these two libraries.

```js
let date = 'Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020'
let momentDate = moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
console.log(momentDate)

let dayJsDate = dayjs(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
console.log(dayJsDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.34/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The question is "*Does anyone know how to to get the date in the Google Sheet as a Date in Mongo?*" I don't see any attempt to answer that.

Comment: Passing unsupported formats to moment.js without parse tokens means it's parsed by the built–in parser, so no different to `new Date(string)`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let date = 'Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020';
date = new Date(date) //date object
console.log(date)
console.log(typeof(date))
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: Thanks.  For me the output is   
"Invalid Date",
 "object",
 "Invalid Date",

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Before downvoting atleast run in console.
Run the code here, it is not invalid date